# 301 redirect header syntax

Tags: php, redirect, syntax, http-headers

In many cases 301 redirection headers are defined like this in PHP:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently'); // or HTTP/1.1
header('Location: /new/path/');
```

However, I noticed that the following definitions for HTTP status code work too:

- `header('HTTP/1.0 301');`
- `header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved');`
- `header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved for some other reason');`

I didn't find any explicit specification saying that `Moved Permanently` part is obligatory.

So is OK to use the short version `header('HTTP/1.0 301');`?

Comment: I never seen this syntax, I always used `header('Location: /my/new/path', true, 301)`. I never set the name of the HTTP status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 1945 section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-6.1) (Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.0), the `Reason-Phrase` is a part of the `Status-Line` but the `Reason-Phrase` may be empty.

[Section 6.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-6.1.1) describes the ABNF for `Reason-Phrase` to be the following:

```
Reason-Phrase  = *<TEXT, excluding CR, LF>
```

The asterisk `*` indicates that the reason phrase may include 0 or more of the characters defined within `<>`.

```
The character "*" preceding an element indicates repetition. The
full form is "<n>*<m>element" indicating at least <n> and at
most <m> occurrences of element. Default values are 0 and
infinity so that "*(element)" allows any number, including zero;
"1*element" requires at least one; and "1*2element" allows one
or two.
```

[RFC 1945 section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-2.1)

Furthermore, you may use any reason phrase you wish without it affecting the protocol.

> The individual values of the numeric status codes defined for
> HTTP/1.0, and an example set of corresponding Reason-Phrase's, are
> presented below. **The reason phrases listed here are only recommended
>
> -- they may be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the    protocol.**